# Dynamic workflow with external class reference

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I am trying to create Dynamic activity using the new WF 4.5 features - C# expression. It works until I add an external class in the expression.The requirement is like this i will create a workflow from VS and then from another application i will dynamically load the xaml file. The activity will contain c# expression . It works fine if no external classes are involved. But whenever there is a external class referenced involved the Compile Expressions method(which actually compile the expression) throws an error -- Unable to load assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve my issue. actually I forgot to place the external dll reference to the appropriate bin folder. Now the dynamic activity is working fine